# OpenGL/Java Learning Curve

Tags: java, opengl

We are looking at speeding up a project with new developers. How long is a typical Java + OpenGL learning curve if anyone has any experience ? The core work is on detailed globe visualization.

Comment: To clarify - we have 2 devs with a couple of years of experience in JOGL and willing to teach the concepts. Knowledge of basic java is expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"If anyone has any experience" - what do you mean by that? If you have people who have experience with Java and with OpenGL in another programming language (C or C++ for example), then learning [JOGL](https://jogl.dev.java.net/) (the Java OpenGL API that's on its way becoming a standard - [JSR-231](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=231)) is going to be easy, because JOGL is only a thin wrapper around OpenGL - it has the same concepts and same structure as the OpenGL API in C.

If your developers do not have any experience with OpenGL or 3D computer graphics, then it's going to be a lot harder.

Comment: I am talking about personal learning experience.

Comment: Ok: I found JOGL easy to learn; I'm a professional Java developer and I've played with OpenGL in C before.

Comment: Understanding the concepts and mathematics (vectors, matrices, transforms, etc.) in computer graphics will be much harder to learn for people who have no experience with computer graphics than learning Java.

Comment: So you would recommend mathematics in addition to plain programming. A lot of CS graduates are not serious mathematecians. I come from an engineering background, vector algebra is the order of the day.

Comment: Yes, to really understand how 3D graphics work you need a good understanding of the mathematics. In OpenGL and JOGL things like vectors, matrices and transforms are directly represented in the API and you need to understand what those things are and how they work. There are many good books about 3D computer graphics.

Answer (score 3):

I went through some of the tutorials on http://nehe.gamedev.net/ to try JOGL without a C background, and I found it easy enough to understand.

Answer (score 0):

JOGL is a thin wrapper around OpenGL, if you know OpenGL, you can do JOGL.

Java - it's easy if you have OO experience in your team, although learning the APIs will take time, as with all new platforms.